# Counting arabic characters based on their shapes

Tags: unicode, arabic

Arabic characters change their shape based on their positions in a word. I have a long arabic text. I want to count all different arabic shapes occuring in the text. However the [codePointAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) function of javascript disappoints me.

For instance, this is arabic "L" => `ل`

and this is arabic "alif" => `ا`

If "alif" comes after "L" in a word they takes this shape together => `لا`

Now javascripts codesPointAt() separates all letters of a word before it outputs the unicode number of the letters. Thus, it sees `ل` and `ا` as different characters, which is not what I want.

I am using PHP as a server-side script. It has no unicode functions as far as I know.

What are my options after that?

Comment: This is the difference between presentation forms and base characters from a Unicode perspective.  See [presentation forms](http://unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html#Pf1) from the Unicode Consortium.

Comment: Since what you want to count are glyphs rather than actual characters, take a look at [fontkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontkit).  The function font.layout(string) will return a GlyphRun object that contains the glyphs required to display the string for presentation.  You could then count those rather than the underlying characters.